# Trying to send data from a html form and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying just to practice manipulating data from a static html page to Node.Js without using Angular, React or other framework libraries. I've installed all of my dependencies and node is serving my index.html, however, I can't seem to get my post method to work. I can't get it to even console.log anything. I've looked at the other stack overflow issues and the documents but can't seem to figure out the issue.

Here is my code and file structure.

HTML:

```
<form id="citySearchForm" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/getcity" method="POST">

        <div>
            <p>Choose a city:</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a city" id="getCitiesInput" name="city"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>

        <div id="weather"></div>

        <p><span id="temp"></span></p>

        <p><span id="wind"></span></p>

 </form>
```

node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(_dirname + "/" + "index.html");
})

app.post('/getcity', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    response = { city : req.body.city };
    console.log(response);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening')});
```

json:

```
{
  "name": "basic_weather_api",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "Just a basic api call",
   "main": "server.js",
   "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "node server.js"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
     "express": "^4.14.1"
   }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested this out locally and it worked after I changed `_dirname` to `__dirname`. Did you end/kill the node server after editing the file?

Comment: I made the change and restarted node. I just updated to  v 1.11.0 maybe that has something to do with it. I'm stumped.

Comment: THIS IS GOLD. I've almost gone to deepweb to scrap this information. TY

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your code and it works perfectly fine.

On submit with city = Test, I see this Json response in browser : `{"city":"Test"}`

Also, I am albe to see your log statement printed. But remember your `console.log()` statement is part of the `node.js` server code, which means your log statement will be printed in server log and not in the browser console. If you are running your node server from terminal using `node server.js` you will see your log printed in the terminal.

If you have modified version of dependencies multiple time, delete `node_modules` directory and try to run `npm install` again.

Comment: Not sure if it is because of the updated dependancies or not but the post just won't log in terminal. i added my package.json to the post thread.

Comment: @LonnieMcGill I just tried with your package.json as well and worked fine for me. If you have tried changing version of dependencies multiple time, simply delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: I re-installed everything and it works. I updated to node 1.11.0 after setting up the dependancies.  Didn't think I would need to delete the json and node modules since I didn't change the dependency version but it seems like you do. Thanks.